# How can I encode JSON objects to pass from Google Appscript over its HTML interface?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

Google Appscript has the ability to pass things from the server side scripting, to client side html.

eg

appscript.gs

```
var htmlServ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("addDetailsBookingForm");
  let order_id = getSheetOrderID(sheet);   //let order_id = "98";
  htmlServ.order = pullOrderStore(order_id) // let's say this is an array
  const html = htmlServ.evaluate();
  html.setWidth(850).setHeight(450);
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.showModalDialog(html, "form");
```

What I'd like to do is pass JSON across using this interface. However, objects are not supported from what I can understand. I can send strings, arrays but not objects.

However, it seems to me that I could turn a JSON object into a string, before sending it, and then parse it client side and turn it back into an object again.

[Taking some inspiration from here,](https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community/c/RH9vEMqfBOI?pli=1) I was wondering if one could do something like

```
  var htmlServ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("addDetailsBookingForm");
  let order_id = "98";

  orderDetailsObject = pullFromWordPressOrder(order_id)
  htmlServ.orderDetailsObject = JSON.stringify(orderDetailsObject)

  Logger.log(htmlServ.orderDetailsObject)
<etc>
```

displayjsonfile.html

```
  <script>
// this will output orderDetailsObject from the server side into orderDetailsObject on the client side. Despite the name, they're totally different variables.
     var orderDetailsObject = <?=orderDetailsObject?>; 
     var product_object = JSON.parse(orderDetailsObject);

console.log(product_object)
var order_id = product_object.id //ToTest
```

example JSON

```
{"id":98,"parent_id":0,"status":"pending","currency":"GBP","version":"6.5.1","prices_include_tax":false,"date_created":"2022-08-11T20:12:58","date_modified":"2022-08-12T13:07:32","discount_total":"0.00","discount_tax":"0.00","shipping_total":"0.00","shipping_tax":"0.00","cart_tax":"0.00","total":"30.00","total_tax":"0.00","customer_id":17,"order_key":"wc_order_f368FMstESsXn","billing":{"first_name":"Freddie","last_name":"Flintoff","company":"","address_1":"a place","address_2":"","city":"a town","state":"derby","postcode":"sk13 7rx","country":"","email":"freddie@example.com","phone":"01234123123"},"shipping":{"first_name":"Freddie","last_name":"Flintoff","company":"","address_1":"a place","address_2":"","city":"a town","state":"derby","postcode":"sk13 7rx","country":"","phone":""},"payment_method":"","payment_method_title":"","transaction_id":"","customer_ip_address":"94.118.139.237","customer_user_agent":"","created_via":"admin","customer_note":"","date_completed":null,"date_paid":"2022-08-11T20:13:46","cart_hash":"","number":"98","meta_data":[{"id":1441,"key":"_new_order_email_sent","value":"true"},{"id":1442,"key":"_automatewoo_order_created","value":"1"}],"line_items":[{"id":50,"name":"Tim's Bike shed","product_id":75,"variation_id":0,"quantity":1,"tax_class":"","subtotal":"30.00","subtotal_tax":"0.00","total":"30.00","total_tax":"0.00","taxes":[],"meta_data":[],"sku":"","price":30,"parent_name":null}],"tax_lines":[],"shipping_lines":[],"fee_lines":[],"coupon_lines":[],"refunds":[],"payment_url":"https://dev1.example.com/checkout/order-pay/98/?pay_for_order=true&key=wc_order_f368FMstESsXn","date_created_gmt":"2022-08-11T20:12:58","date_modified_gmt":"2022-08-12T13:07:32","date_completed_gmt":null,"date_paid_gmt":"2022-08-11T20:13:46","currency_symbol":"£","_links":{"self":[{"href":"https://dev1.example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/98"}],"collection":[{"href":"https://dev1.example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders"}],"customer":[{"href":"https://dev1.example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/customers/17"}]}}
```

Currently the JSON object outputs in the html as

```
     var orderDetailsObject = '{\x22id\x22:98,\x22parent_id\x22:0,\x22status\x22:\x22pending\x22,\x22currency\x22:\x22GBP\x22,\x22version\x22:\x226.5.1\x22,\x22prices_include_tax\x22:false,\x22date_created\x22:\x222022-08-11T20:12:58\x22,\x22date_modified\x22:\x222022-08-12T13:07:32\x22,\x22discount_total\x22:\x220.00\x22,\x22discount_tax\x22:\x220.00\x22,\x22shipping_total\x22:\x220.00\x22,\x22shipping_tax\x22:\x220.00\x22,\x22cart_tax\x22:\x220.00\x22,\x22total\x22:\x2230.00\x22,\x22total_tax\x22:\x220.00\x22,\x22customer_id\x22:17,\x22order_key\x22:\x22wc_order_f368FMstESsXn\x22,\x22billing\x22:{\x22first_name\x22:\x22Freddie\x22,\x22last_name\x22:\x22Flintoff\x22,\x22company\x22:\x22\x22,\x22address_1\x22:\x22a place\x22,\x22address_2\x22:\x22\x22,\x22city\x22:\x22a town\x22,\x22state\x22:\x22derby\x22,\x22postcode\x22:\x22sk13 7rx\x22,\x22country\x22:\x22\x22,\x22email\x22:\x22freddie@example.com\x22,\x22phone\x22:\x2201234123123\x22},\x22shipping\x22:{\x22first_name\x22:\x22Freddie\x22,\x22last_name\x22:\x22Flintoff\x22,\x22company\x22:\x22\x22,\x22address_1\x22:\x22a place\x22,\x22address_2\x22:\x22\x22,\x22city\x22:\x22a town\x22,\x22state\x22:\x22derby\x22,\x22postcode\x22:\x22sk13 7rx\x22,\x22country\x22:\x22\x22,\x22phone\x22:\x22\x22},\x22payment_method\x22:\x22\x22,\x22payment_method_title\x22:\x22\x22,\x22transaction_id\x22:\x22\x22,\x22customer_ip_address\x22:\x2294.118.139.237\x22,\x22customer_user_agent\x22:\x22\x22,\x22created_via\x22:\x22admin\x22,\x22customer_note\x22:\x22\x22,\x22date_completed\x22:null,\x22date_paid\x22:\x222022-08-11T20:13:46\x22,\x22cart_hash\x22:\x22\x22,\x22number\x22:\x2298\x22,\x22meta_data\x22:[{\x22id\x22:1441,\x22key\x22:\x22_new_order_email_sent\x22,\x22value\x22:\x22true\x22},{\x22id\x22:1442,\x22key\x22:\x22_automatewoo_order_created\x22,\x22value\x22:\x221\x22}],\x22line_items\x22:[{\x22id\x22:50,\x22name\x22:\x22Tim\x27s Bike shed\x22,\x22product_id\x22:75,\x22variation_id\x22:0,\x22quantity\x22:1,\x22tax_class\x22:\x22\x22,\x22subtotal\x22:\x2230.00\x22,\x22subtotal_tax\x22:\x220.00\x22,\x22total\x22:\x2230.00\x22,\x22total_tax\x22:\x220.00\x22,\x22taxes\x22:[],\x22meta_data\x22:[],\x22sku\x22:\x22\x22,\x22price\x22:30,\x22parent_name\x22:null}],\x22tax_lines\x22:[],\x22shipping_lines\x22:[],\x22fee_lines\x22:[],\x22coupon_lines\x22:[],\x22refunds\x22:[],\x22payment_url\x22:\x22https:\/\/dev1.example.com\/checkout\/order-pay\/98\/?pay_for_order=true\x26key=wc_order_f368FMstESsXn\x22,\x22date_created_gmt\x22:\x222022-08-11T20:12:58\x22,\x22date_modified_gmt\x22:\x222022-08-12T13:07:32\x22,\x22date_completed_gmt\x22:null,\x22date_paid_gmt\x22:\x222022-08-11T20:13:46\x22,\x22currency_symbol\x22:\x22£\x22,\x22_links\x22:{\x22self\x22:[{\x22href\x22:\x22https:\/\/dev1.example.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v3\/orders\/98\x22}],\x22collection\x22:[{\x22href\x22:\x22https:\/\/dev1.example.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v3\/orders\x22}],\x22customer\x22:[{\x22href\x22:\x22https:\/\/dev1.example.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v3\/customers\/17\x22}]}}';
```

Clearly - it's being encoded/decoded poorly - specifically speech marks are coming out encoded.

Is this expected - or is there a better way to do this?

To be clear - it works, but it feels like it isn't pretty... not to mention not best practice.

Comment: You have to parse the JSON in the client.  Right now what you are doing is parsing it in the template (server) before the page has loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to pass a JSON object to the client.

Code.gs

```
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}

function showTest() {
  var myObject = { name: "MyTest", value: 100 };
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("HTML_Test");
  html.myObject = JSON.stringify(myObject);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html.evaluate(),"Test");
}
```

HTML_Test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="name" type="text">
    <br>
    <input id="value" type="text">
    <script>
      var myObject = <?= myObject ?>;
      (function() {
        myObject = JSON.parse(myObject);
        document.getElementById("name").value = myObject.name;
        document.getElementById("value").value = myObject.value;
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values) the parameters and return values that can cause problem where passing objects with google.script.run.

The date has got me in the past.  If you have a date in a cell and the cell is formatted to display it as a string, the use getDisplayValues() and pass it as a string and then use new Date() constructor to return it back to a date on the server side.

Other than that pretty much any object will work that can be stringified.